# Multi-dimensional array as a pointer - where are addresses of subarrays stored?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

In the tutorial video about pointers (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuegQmMdy8M) there are the following code and illustration:

```c
int B[2][3]; // we define an array
```

[image]

The following facts about that code were given:

- Printing B (or &B[0]) would return 400 (the address of the first sub-array)
- Printing *B (or B[0] or &B[0][0]) would return 400 (the address of the first element in the first sub-array)

I struggle a bit with an understanding of that. How can `B` and `*B` have the same value? We can clearly see in the illustration that under address 400 there is a value 2. If `B` = 400, then `*B` = 2!

My understanding is that the value of `B` would be the address of the first element of the outer array in the memory. Then, the `*B` would return the address of the first sub-array in the memory.

According to the illustration, `B` (not shown) has a value 400. Then, under 400, there is the first value of the first sub-array. Where are the addresses of the sub-arrays stored?

Comment: Not everything has to be *stored*, if it can be *computed* instead. Also, types matter. If you don't consider types, then `B == 400` and `*B == 400` may be difficult to understand.

Comment: @EOF I found this nice image: https://web.njit.edu/~sohna/cs288/hello-memap.pdf It shows exactly how my understanding of multi-dimensional arrays would look like in memory. The argv stores an address of the first sub-array (first string). Next to that address is an address of the second sub-array (second string). And so on. These two ways of storing arrays in memory are completely different and I do not understand why. According to the image from the video argv should point directly to "hello".

Comment: @Loreno: This pdf is very confusing: the memory map displays memory contents from high addresses to low addresses from top to bottom. I have not seen this for decades. Better represent memory from low to high addresses as you will see in debuggers.

Comment: @chqrlie RIght, but that is representation detail. I was more focused on the values in the memory. As shown in the image, `argv` is organized differently than in the image I originally posted in my question. My guess is that `argv` is not a "real" array and that's why memory layout is different?

Comment: `argv` is a real array of pointers. The article shows the argv array and the strings its elements point to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B` and `*B` do not have the same *value*, they have different types, namely `int[2][3]` and `int[3]`, but they have the same address in memory, ie: `400` as shown.

Think of `B` as a building and `B[0]` as the ground floor.  They do not have the same *value* (in $) but they have the same address (and zip code).

This comparison works for passing `B` or `B[0]` to a function (delivery company): you are not passing the actual building, but merely its street *address* and the *type* name.

Comment: Do you mean that the values of B and *B are not the same, because their types use different amounts of bytes? So, B's value takes 24 bytes (the entire array), while *B's value takes 12 bytes (first sub-array).

Comment: Does it also mean that we're not able to say what would the value of *B be just by looking at the memory segments (we don't know the code, we only see the memory bytes). By looking at the memory segments from the image I pasted, I'd assume that *B = 2 knowing that B = 400. If I understand it correctly, the dereference operator is not just going to some memory address and reading its value. It is actually more convoluted and takes into account the type of the pointer.

Comment: @Loreno: exactly: one cannot tell what `*B` means from just the address in memory. The type is necessary.  The size is not enough either: `int B;`, `int B[1]`, int B[1][1]` all have the same size and could live in memory at the same address but `*B` has a different meaning, if any.

Comment: @Loreno The dereference operator "is not just going to some memory address and reading its value" in *any* case. Consider `int * x; ...; *x = 2;`. Here, the dereference operator doesn't read anything stored at the location pointed to by `x`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sure, I was focusing on the reading part only.

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie. Could you also have a look at https://web.njit.edu/~sohna/cs288/hello-memap.pdf? Why argv is stored in memory so differently compared to my initial example?

Comment: `argv` has a completely different type. It is an array of pointers. Each pointer points to an array of `ohar` (strictly speaking, to the first element of such array). These latter arrays of `char` need not be contiguous in memory, and each one can have different size. Typically different strings have different lengths. String length need not be stored anywhere, it is determined by the null terminator. So this representation is good for an array of strings. OTOH rows of a matrix, for example, all have the same fixed length, so such representation would be pointless for matrices.